# Difference in printing a function and calling a function involving Python Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, reverse

So I have a function that gives me the dictionary in the reverse the order of insertion.

```
a = {1:2, 2:5, 6:7}

def reverse_dict(dict): 
  reverse_list = list(reversed(list(dict.items())))

  di = {}

  for a, b in reverse_list: 
      di[a] = b 

  return di
```

However, If I call the function, my output is the same as the original dictionary but if i print it my output is the desired outcome.

```
print(reverse_dict(a))
>>> {6: 7, 2: 5, 1: 2}

reverse_dict(a)
>>> {1: 2, 2: 5, 6: 7}
```

Why is this happening and what is the fix ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour from your example.

Comment: are you getting the reversed dict in both of them are the normal dict in them ?

Comment: `>>> a
{1: 2, 2: 5, 6: 7}
>>> reverse_dict(a)
{6: 7, 2: 5, 1: 2}
>>> print(reverse_dict(a))
{6: 7, 2: 5, 1: 2}` Not so clear in the comment, but yes. It works as expected in both cases.

Comment: I too can't reproduce.

Comment: It is happening, I am working in Google Colab, maybe something to do with that ?

Comment: can't reproduce too...

Comment: @WuDaozi Share your colab file. So we can look at it.

Comment: as an aside, `list(reversed(list(dict.items())))` stop using `list` needlessly.  `reversed(some_dict.items())` gives you a nice, efficient reversed iterator over the items in a dict. There is no need to create intermediate lists.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `reversed(dict.items())` will raise error saying `TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not reversible` in any python version less than 3.8. `reversed(dict.items())` works from python3.8

Comment: Which exact version of Python 3 are you using?

Comment: The exact Python version is relevant here, because `dict` behavior changed in Python 3.6 and 3.7. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537308/674064

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I  am using python 3.6.9